# should the voting be locked for question that is closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should a post be locked to be voted down <strike>(or up)</strike> after it gets closed? All the intention is to make the OP(usually newbies) realize the basics and methodology of questioning .. 
When a question gets closed and by the comments entered by fellow members OP realizes it! Then why not lock that question for <strike>vote-up or</strike> vote-down?

Comment: I doubt this will fly. People love their downvotes too much to let this happen.

Comment: my point is why one should downvote a question when it is already been closed for a reason?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it makes sense, I doubt this idea will be very popular because people have a natural incentive to "punish" bad questions. Disallowing voting on a closed question means they can't "take it out" on the user. On the other hand, there are many very good closed questions that *should* continue to get votes.

Comment: @Mysticial, alright voting up is other thing .. voting down is something else! What you mean by `punish` ? to discourage newbies?? stackoverflow is to help each other we are not on war!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Don't forget that this is the internet. People tend to have a lot less "restraint" online. If you were on the street, and you see some guy getting hit with tomatoes, would you join in? What about a post on stackoverflow that has 10 downvotes?

Comment: well. so your point is more and more people should grab tomato and `punish` the guy..!

Comment: I don't tend to downvote if it has already been declared as closed or voted for deletion! The OP needed a suggestion and he has got it .. why do I have to poke in and downvote again!? I mean what is the point!

Comment: Pretty much. It's a human behavior thing. We're all inclined to do "negative" things on other people. But in modern society, we better restrain ourselves in person because there can be severe consequences for lack of self-control. But online, all hell breaks loose - especially if you can do it anonymously. This is one of the reasons why people here brutally defend anonymous downvotes. Because it lets them behave without restraint and without consequences.

Comment: I completely agree on that .. so what is your opinion? should there be a lock on downvote for a question if it is closed or let the post face opinion of the people by up or down vote??

Comment: I'm in favor of leaving it as is. The current system already does a pretty good job of protecting downvoted questions from pile-on downvoting. (questions with -4 are knocked off the homepage) It would also be inconsistent to allow one type of voting, but not the other.

Comment: glad to discuss with you :) thanks for the participation..

Comment: And am still against considering votes as punishment rather than as disagreement ..

Comment: I don't agree with your suggestion here, and I especially don't agree with only locking downvotes but allowing upvotes. If you're going to allow voting at all then all types of votes should be acceptable. As Mardar notes in their answer, votes on closed questions are especially important for edits made to those questions.

Comment: I find it a point.. thanks for adding..

Comment: "Should a post be locked to be voted down (or up) after it gets closed?" No. No, it should not.

Comment: LOL I am being punished here :P

Comment: @JackManey, please read the accepted answer .. it's been discussed already and concluded.. this question is almost closed :/ there was no need to downvote it again! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Voting is part of the process of improving a closed question (even though practically it very rarely happens).

If a closed question is edited to be improved, it should be voted on to reflect its new state.

Voting a question is unrelated to its closed/opened state. A question is voted down if it isn't clear, or if no research effort is visible. Closing is done when the question is either unanswerable, or not worth answering. Often, these go hand to hand, and they partially have the sting effect we want for new "offensive" users. They ask a crap question, they get closed and mass downvoted in 2 minutes, then they (hopefully) learn that their question was lousy.

Comment: @Naruto! I am talking about voting down the **question** .. not about reopening or voting it up! neither about **closed answer** (btw what is closed answer now????

Comment: my point is simple! To make the op realize about bad question, closing it would be sufficient (or the downvotes before closing) why people still should continue to vote it down! when it is already been (question) declared as an inappropriate?

Comment: What is a closed answer ?

Comment: I heard it for first time as well! Madara has mystic jutsu's :P

Comment: Pathetic mortals, wait until my Juubi is awakened completely! All jokes aside, voting a **QUESTION** is unrelated to its closed/opened state. A question is voted down if it isn't clear, or if no research effort is visible. Closing is done when the question is either unanswerable, or not worth answering. Often, these go hand to hand, and they partially have the sting effect we want for new "offensive" users. They ask a crap question, they get closed and mass downvoted in 2 minutes, then they (hopefully) learn that their question was lousy.

Comment: way to go madara .. that's much satisfactory answer..

Comment: please add those words from your last comment! They bring up good points! BTW let me know when naruto will fight with you in shippuden anime! :( I am tired of waiting because of these fillers :(

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind': Will do. P.S. I'm heading to the anime director's house right now to... share... how much I like his fillers.

Comment: haha .. please do .. :D

Answer (score 5):

Closure and voting are orthogonal:

- A question which is closed can still be good and popular:

  [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)
- A question which is perfectly acceptable can be unpopular:

  [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)
- A question can be both unpopular and closed (obviously):

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029651/fastest-way-in-c-sharp-to-iterate-through-all-guids-possible
- Finally a question can be both popular and not closed (of course!):

  [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

I don't see a good argument to couple these concerns. Preventing people from doing something will not *teach them anything*, and in general there's nothing wrong with the current system (in that it works on the large numbers which is the whole point of voting).

Comment: thanks for the response :)